# how to remove columns except the last one?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to move the columns except for the last, I do not know if there was any way to do it with awk or sed or some other line command

```
 ...
    00000000: 30327c30 30303131 36333132 567c317c  0|2011002136|1|V
    00000010: 44204149 56452045 4d415449 544e4549  IA DE EVITAMIENT
    00000020: 7c007c4f 30327c00 302d3131 37312d33  O|.|.|2011-03-17
    00000030: 3a393020 303a3035 33427c30 38313957   09:50:00|B3W918
    00000040: 327c317c 7c39397c 4f52544f 4f4d7c53  |1|2|99|OTROS|MO
    00000050: 414b4f54 7c007c52 7c007c00 36312d47  TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
    00000060: 7c54527c 444e4f43 52494355 204e5520  |RT|CONDUCIR UN 
    00000070: 49484556 4f4c5543 524f5020 414e5520  VEHICULO POR UNA
    ...
```

i tried, but only delete the first column

```
$ cat file | sed -E $'s/ +/\t/g' | cut -f2-
```

i want this result. The last column

```
    ...
    0|2011002136|1|V
    IA DE EVITAMIENT
    O|.|.|2011-03-17
    09:50:00|B3W918
    |1|2|99|OTROS|MO
    TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
    |RT|CONDUCIR UN 
    VEHICULO POR UNA
    ...
```

Comment: Do you want to keep the spaces in the front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're just trying to get last 16 chars.

```
$ sed 's/.*\(.\{16\}\)/\1/' file
0|2011002136|1|V
IA DE EVITAMIENT
O|.|.|2011-03-17
 09:50:00|B3W918
|1|2|99|OTROS|MO
TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
|RT|CONDUCIR UN
VEHICULO POR UNA
```

---

I took a closer look at your sample and realized that it is a hex dump generated with `xxd -e`. If you want to obtain the original file, use following:

```
$ xxd -r file | xxd -e | xxd -r > original_file
$ cat original_file
0|2011002136|1|VIA DE EVITAMIENTO|||2011-03-17 09:50:00|B3W918|1|2|99|OTROS|MOTOKAR||||G-16|RT|CONDUCIR UN VEHICULO POR UNA
```

<sub>P.S: `original_file` contains NUL bytes but they're not shown on terminal.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to print final 16 chars with grep:

`grep -Po '.{16}$' file`

or

`grep -o '.\{16\}$' file`

- `-P` for perl regexes
- `-o` for only-matching

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the first 5 space-separated fields.

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -E 's/(\s+\S+){5}\s+//' file
0|2011002136|1|V
IA DE EVITAMIENT
O|.|.|2011-03-17
09:50:00|B3W918
|1|2|99|OTROS|MO
TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
|RT|CONDUCIR UN
VEHICULO POR UNA
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/\([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]*\)\{5\}[[:space:]]*//' file
0|2011002136|1|V
IA DE EVITAMIENT
O|.|.|2011-03-17
09:50:00|B3W918
|1|2|99|OTROS|MO
TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
|RT|CONDUCIR UN
VEHICULO POR UNA
```

Comment: I don;t think there's any tool I love but as mentioned previously I do appreciate sed and use it almost every day. In this case I'm using sed because cut works on single char delimiters and idk if the spaces in the example are tabs or blanks and if they are blanks I'm not sure if the real data starts with the number of blanks in  the question, etc. My gut instinct is that the spaces between the last 2 columns are tabs while the rest blanks but idk. With the sed solution I posted I know it'll work no matter what those spaces are and no matter how many of them there are,

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solutions don't seem to have been mentioned.

You really just want the characters beginning in the 52nd position. So use cut:

Input:

```
▶ cat > FILE <<EOF
    00000000: 30327c30 30303131 36333132 567c317c  0|2011002136|1|V
    00000010: 44204149 56452045 4d415449 544e4549  IA DE EVITAMIENT
    00000020: 7c007c4f 30327c00 302d3131 37312d33  O|.|.|2011-03-17
    00000030: 3a393020 303a3035 33427c30 38313957   09:50:00|B3W918
    00000040: 327c317c 7c39397c 4f52544f 4f4d7c53  |1|2|99|OTROS|MO
    00000050: 414b4f54 7c007c52 7c007c00 36312d47  TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
    00000060: 7c54527c 444e4f43 52494355 204e5520  |RT|CONDUCIR UN
    00000070: 49484556 4f4c5543 524f5020 414e5520  VEHICULO POR UNA
EOF
```

Output:

```
▶ cut -c52- FILE
0|2011002136|1|V
IA DE EVITAMIENT
O|.|.|2011-03-17
 09:50:00|B3W918
|1|2|99|OTROS|MO
TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
|RT|CONDUCIR UN
VEHICULO POR UNA
```

---

Note that cut can be emulated in sed this way, as noted in a comment:

```
▶ sed -E 's/.{51}//' FILE
```

---

Another way is to use AWK to set the field widths, if you have a version of AWK that supports it like GNU AWK, nawk (Mac OS X) etc.

```
▶ gawk 'BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "15 9 9 9 9 16"} {print $6}' FILE
0|2011002136|1|V
IA DE EVITAMIENT
O|.|.|2011-03-17
 09:50:00|B3W918
|1|2|99|OTROS|MO
TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
|RT|CONDUCIR UN
VEHICULO POR UNA
```

The benefit of the AWK solution is, while a little more effort to set up, it communicates more information about your expectations of the data to the reader of your code.

To figure out where all the columns begin, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> in Vim after positioning the cursor on them.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print "    "$NF}' file
...
0|2011002136|1|V
EVITAMIENT
O|.|.|2011-03-17
09:50:00|B3W918
|1|2|99|OTROS|MO
TOKAR|.|.|.|G-16
UN
UNA
...
```

Comment: Always add explanations to your answers to explain to the OP and others what you are solving

Answer (score 0):

if your data in `d` file, tried on gnu awk

```
awk -F' [a-f0-9]{8}  ' '{print $2}' d
```

tried on gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/.*\s[a-f0-9]{8}\s{2,}(.*)/\1/' d
```